# MySQL: Select/sort entries with the fastest rising scores

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, datetime

I have 2 tables.

The first contains entries/submissions:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | user |
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | test  |  25  |
| 2  | foo   |  3   |
| 3  | bar   |  12  |
| 4  | hello |  2   |
| 5  | world |  6   |
+----+-------+------+
```

The second contains scores. Each score has value between 1 and 5. Not every entry has a score. (assume 'DATETIME' as standard datetime value)

```
+----+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
| id | score | entry | user | scored_date         |
+----+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
| 1  |   4   |  1    |  5   | 2016-06-05 10:10:00 |
| 2  |   3   |  1    |  12  | 2016-06-05 10:20:00 |
| 3  |   5   |  3    |  6   | 2016-06-05 10:30:00 |
| 4  |   2   |  2    |  23  | 2016-06-05 10:40:00 |
| 5  |   3   |  2    |  46  | 2016-06-05 10:50:00 |
| 6  |   5   |  3    |  14  | 2016-06-05 10:60:00 |
| 7  |   6   |  3    |  32  | 2016-06-05 11:00:00 |
| 8  |   5   |  4    |  9   | 2016-06-05 11:10:00 |
| 9  |   1   |  2    |  4   | 2016-06-05 11:20:00 |
| 10 |   2   |  4    |  2   | 2016-06-05 11:30:00 |
| 11 |   4   |  2    |  18  | 2016-06-05 11:40:00 |
| 12 |   5   |  1    |  8   | 2016-06-05 11:50:00 |
| 13 |   3   |  2    |  32  | 2016-06-05 12:00:00 |
| 14 |   4   |  1    |  28  | 2016-06-05 12:10:00 |
+----+-------+-------+------+---------------------+
```

I'm trying to sort entries based on how "fast" they're rising. A good example is the "Rising" list on a website like threadless.com https://www.threadless.com/threadless/designs?status=open&sort=rising

Assuming current time: 12:30:00
Expected results of entries sorted by "rising". Perhaps based on the last hour (11:30:00 - 12:30:00), then last 2 hours (10:30:00 - 12:30:00) etc

```
Entry table results (Last 1 hour 11:30:00 - 12:30:00)
+----+-----------+
| id | score_sum |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |     9     |    
| 2  |     7     |
| 4  |     2     |
| 3  |     0     |
| 5  |     0     |
+----+-----------+


Entry table results (Last 2 hour 10:30:00 - 12:30:00)
+----+-----------+
| id | score_sum |
+----+-----------+
| 3  |    16     |
| 2  |    13     |
| 1  |     9     |    
| 4  |     7     |
| 5  |     0     |
+----+-----------+
```

I'm guessing multiple time frames may be needed, since there are situations when, say, there are no scores in the past 1 hour, or if there are only 2 scores in the past 3 hours, but 100 scores in the past 5 hours. Thus the results from just the past 1 hour will be inaccurate or less meaningful.

Given this premise, I can't figure out the logic behind such a SQL statement. I'm also unsure of how to combine different timeframes to make the results conherent and meanginful.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If your first table is called foo and the second table is bar - then

Solution #1:

```
SELECT foo.id AS id, SUM(COALESCE(bar.score,0)) AS score_sum
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  ON foo.id = bar.entry
    AND bar.scored_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY foo.id
ORDER BY score_sum DESC;
```

Solution #2

```
SELECT foo.id AS id, SUM(COALESCE(bar.score,0)) AS score_sum
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  ON foo.id = bar.entry
    AND bar.scored_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
GROUP BY foo.id
ORDER BY score_sum DESC;
```

---

To combine them, use the longest (most inclusive) time period as the JOIN condition. Then use you other conditions as column definitions. You can play around with this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4921/4) showing the below code example.

```
SELECT foo.id AS id
    , SUM(COALESCE(bar.score,0) * 
            IF(bar.scored_date >= CAST('2016-06-05 11:00:00' AS DATETIME)
                ,1,0)) AS MereOneHOurInterval
    , SUM(COALESCE(bar.score,0)) AS BiggestInterval
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN bar
  ON foo.id = bar.entry
    AND bar.scored_date >= CAST('2016-06-05 10:00:00' AS DATETIME)
GROUP BY foo.id
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I get your solution, but it took 2 separate queries for the 2 timeframes. Is there a way to combine them logically? Such that scores in the past 1 hour has more "weight", the scores in the next hour has less weight, so on and so forth (for up to maybe 6 time intervals)

Comment: Saw your edit. Does it make sense if I change CAST('2016-06-05 11:00:00' AS DATETIME) to DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 HOURS) ?

Comment: @MikeFeng - I guess it makes sense: it's your business rule. I needed to use a constant to show you the technique based on the datetime values as found in your sample data.